# Getting error message from require() using golang, and go-ethereum?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-debugging, golang

From everything I've been able to find, the only way you can get the error message from `require()` is by using remix which isn't practical for dealing with production issues. Therefore, I'm wondering how one can retrieve the error message, either using the geth console or go-ethereum library.